# Join returning empty file as output in linux/shell

Tags: linux, join

I am trying to merge two files on the basis of key column using join but my output file is returning empty. I cant figure out the reason.

My file 1 looks like this

```
chr-pos_b37     chr     pos_b37 ID      ref_b37 alt_b37 pos_b38 ref_b38 alt_b38
1-10020 1       10020   rs775809821     AA      A       10020   AA      A
1-10039 1       10039   rs978760828     A       C       10039   A       C
```

My file 2 looks like this

```
chr-pos chr     pos     Effect.Meta     Baseline.Meta   Beta.meta       var.meta        sdE.meta        chi.meta        p.meta  dir.meta
1-11008 1       11008   G       C       -0.0303280157171869     0.000220956591708596    0.014864608696787       4.16275672171384        0.0413221       -+-
1-11012 1       11012   G       C       -0.0303279257228457     0.000220956947453249    0.0148646206629449      4.16272531482656        0.0413229       -+-
```

Command which I am using is

```
join -1 1 -2 1 -o1.4,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5,2.6,2.7,2.8,2.9,2.10  <(sort -k1,1 file1) <(sort -k1,1 file2) > rsID-file3.txt
```

My final goal is to have 4th column from file 1 added as first column in file 2 and output be in file 3. I have tried a lot of variations but my file is still empty. I can do this in R but my files are really huge.

Any lead? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you sure there are any matches in the first field?

Comment: yes I used grep 1-11008 from file 2 to search in file 1 and their were matches.

Comment: Can it be because of spaces in my files?

Comment: Your input redirection won't work. sort to two temp files.

Comment: I tried sorting to temporary files, my file 1 is a huge file and job got killed. I used the command " sort -k 1 file1.txt > sorted-file1.txt". Is there any way around for this?

Comment: > I tried sorting to temporary files,   ... for what result?

Comment: > job got killed ... of course o result in this case